# Adding widget in callback in GTK

Tags: python, widget, gtk

How can I add a new widget from a callback function within a class? For example, I have a Gtk.Box and Gtk.Button and I want to add Gtk.Label to the Gtk.Box from callback function connected to button click. (this code doesn't work)

```
import gi
import os
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import GLib, Gtk, GObject, Gio

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Delete Screenshots")

        self.main_grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.main_grid.set_row_homogeneous(True)
        self.add(self.main_grid)

        self.screen_label = Gtk.Label()
        self.screen_label.set_text("Test Label")
        self.screen_label2 = Gtk.Label()
        self.screen_label2.set_text("Test Label2")

        self.label_box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        self.label_box.homogeneous = True

        self.button_search = Gtk.Button(label="Search")
        self.button_search.connect("clicked", self.on_button_search_clicked)

        self.button_delete = Gtk.Button(label="Delete")
        self.button_delete.connect("clicked", self.on_button_delete_clicked)

        self.main_grid.add(self.button_search);
        self.main_grid.attach(self.button_delete, 1, 0, 1, 1);
        self.main_grid.attach(self.label_box, 0, 1, 1, 1)

    def on_button_search_clicked(self, widget):
        self.label_box.pack_start(self.screen_label, True, True, 0)

    def on_button_delete_clicked(self, widget):
        print("Delete")

win = MainWindow()
win.set_default_size(50, 30)
win.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER_ALWAYS)
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

How to add something to label_box from on_button_search_clicked?

Comment: What you're using there is Gtk3, **not** pyGtk.

Comment: I think you have to call `show()` on your `screen_label` widget after adding it in your callback, because it was not attached to any parent when you initially called `win.show_all()`.

Comment: Thank you so much,  Sven Festersen, problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is basically correct. However all widgets need to be shown by either calling `show()` on them or `show_all()` on a parent widget. In your code, `show_all()` is called on the `MainWindow` instance. At that time, the widget you are adding in your callback is not attached to the window or any of its children. It will thus not be included in the `show_all()` call.

To fix this, simply call `show()` on your label in the callback:

```
...

def on_button_search_clicked(self, widget):
    self.label_box.pack_start(self.screen_label, True, True, 0)
    self.screen_label.show()

...
```